# Slick AST Library with ignore case operations

Tags: scala, slick

I have asked this question already in the [slick](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/re5sym_uMBo) google group. Posting it here if looking for help from ppl who do not check the group.

I am trying to implement a filter similar to [scala-kendo](https://github.com/thenewmotion/scala-kendoui) . We had already developed this filter functionality using the plain queries. Now, I am trying to convert it to slick expressions, similar to what slick-kendo has done.
I need to implement case insensitive filtering. However, I am not able to find out how to do that. The members in [scala.slick.ast.Library](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.3/api/index.html#scala.slick.ast.Library$) provides methods with case sensitive search only.

**EDIT:**

Adding the code:

```
private def predicate(e: E, f: Filter) = {
    val (c, v) = (colNode(e, f.field), LiteralNode(f.value))
    val L = Library
    def \(fs: FunctionSymbol, nodes: Node*) = fs.typed[Boolean](nodes: _*)
    Column.forNode[Boolean](f.operator match {
      case "EqualTo" => \(L.==, c, v)
      case "NotEqualTo" => \(L.Not, \(L.==, c, v))
      case "GreaterThen" => \(L.>, c, v)
      case "GreaterThenOrEqualTo" => \(L.>=, c, v)
      case "LessThen" => \(L.<, c, v)
      case "LessThenOrEqualTo" => \(L.<=, c, v)
      case "StartsWith" => \(L.StartsWith, c, v)
      case "StartsWithIgnore" => \(L.StartsWith, c, v)
      case "EndsWith" => \(L.EndsWith, c, v)
      case "Contains" => \(L.Like, c, LiteralNode(s"%${f.value}%"))
      case "DoesNotContain" => \(L.Not, \(L.Like, c, LiteralNode(s"%${f.value}%")))
    })
  }
```

As you can see above, there are methods like `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` etc in `Library`, but I need something like `StartsWithIgnoreCase`, `EndsWithIgnoreCase` etc

Can someone provide any suggestions to implement this feature I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution is found. Pasting here for others benefit. Went through the slick codebase and found  out how to covert node to column and apply lowercase on column.

```
case "EqualToIgnoreCase" => \(L.==, (Column.forNode[String](c).toLowerCase).toNode, LiteralNode(f.value.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want something like here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0-RC3/queries.html#sorting-and-filtering - see the 4. example "val q4 = coffees.filter ...". This part of the docs is also valid for slick 2.x.

Comment: Nope. That is not I am looking for. I am trying to build slick expression from some generic filters sent from the frontend. Using Library api, I am able to convert the UI Filter object to Slick query expressions. However, I am not able to get ignore case working,